# Create a downloading function

Tags: php

I'm trying to update a module from dolibarr software but I'm really new with php programmation. This module displays a table which is taken data from MySQL database and I want to save this table inside csv file, then able to download this file directly on my machine.

This is the last part from my script.php :

```
   // mysql database connection details
    $host = "localhost";
    $username = "root";
    $password = "root";
    $dbname = "dolibarr";

    // open connection to mysql database
    $connection = mysqli_connect($host, $username, $password, $dbname) or die("Connection Error " . mysqli_error($connection));

    // fetch mysql table rows
    $sql = "select * from llx_parts";
    $result = mysqli_query($connection, $sql) or die("Selection Error " . mysqli_error($connection));

    $fp = fopen('parts.csv', 'w');

    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
    {
        fputcsv($fp, $row);
    }

    fclose($fp);

    //close the db connection
    mysqli_close($connection);
```

It works very well, but now I want to get the posibility to download this file because the software is located on a distant server. 
For example, How I could create a button which let to download my file directly on my machine ?

Thank you so much !

Comment: PHP functions: `readfile` or `fpassthru`

Comment: @u_mulder Both functions let to read a file, but I want to download a file directly on my machine. Are you sure I need to use this functions ?

Comment: I wrote this kind of things : `$file = '/var/www/html/dolibarr/htdocs/parts/parts.csv';
 
   header('Content-disposition: '.$file);
   header('Content-type: application/octetstream');
 
   readfile($file);`

But it displays the file, not download it